# How do I delete a folder named " (double quotation mark) on windows xp

Tags: file-io, windows-xp

I have a several folders on one of my drives named `"`. So, the path would be `C:\some_path\"` Of course, when I try to delete it, I get an error message

> The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

How do I delete these folders?

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=320081, i.e. `rd \S "\\?\C:\some_path"` does not help.

Short file names shown with the swith `/x` i.e. `dir /x` does not help either.

I have tried two utilities, DelinvFile and Unlocker. They are not able to delete these folders either.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about `rd /S "C:\\some_path\\\""`? (May need to be done from a batch file...)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, does not work either. Neither in a batch file. Why would a batch file rather work by the way?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if the command prompt handles escape chars via `\`, but I've definitely used them in batch files before...